# How to add new set of options in mat-select

Tags: angular, mat-select

Want to add new set of options on `selectChange` event of mat-select. is it possible?

**sample** - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtc9hx-f43vwp?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.ts

Above is my sample, on that i have rendered 2 mat-select. on `selectCHange` event i am passing corresponding mat-select reference and trying to empty options and try to assign new data's but I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your example a little bit to get it to work.

The Options itself are being stored in a QueryList which cannot be modified.
See https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtc9hx-wsfqjs?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.ts